# java android load items to listview from database?

Tags: java, android

Okay so i have a database, and i want it so you can favorite items.

Would i make it so you can save items then it will load it into a list view?

this is my load thing

```
//Calls the database, gets a list of names.
    // if listofnames.size()==0 keep name, otherwise
    // change name to first name.
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    favList = db.getName();
    if(favList.size()>0){
        name.setText(favList.get(0));
```

But that just sets a text i want it to add items..

Comment: Put more info and code.. so that people can understand what are the variables you're using and why ..

Answer (score 1):

You may use `ArrayAdapter` or `SimpleAdapter` or `BaseAdapter` - through which you may bind dataSource (`List<T>`) to the `ListView`.

Comment: Or even better - `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Comment: @MisterSquonk - Yes! but in OP, ArrayList<T> is used so I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        //get the names from database
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<E>(this,R.layout.xml_filename,your_list);
    }
}
```

Remember in this case your xml file should be the TextView (I.e the items what list view should contain). You cannot pass an xml file with a ListView directly.

If you have still some problem, then post your code which can be solved.

You can follow the given link for more clarification.
    http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html